# How to use Android DialogFragment setStyle()

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to setStyle to my custom dialog that extends dialogFragment,
constructor looks like:

```
MyCustomDialog() {
  super();
  setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
}
```

and I still see the frame around my layout.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Try calling in `onCreate(...)` instead and not in the constructor.

Comment: @Hoochwo Take a look at FragmentDialog(Support).java in API demos which does what you want.

Comment: I test it, in my case it only works calling the styling in the constructor.public BaseDialogFragment() {
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_AlertDialog);
    }

Answer (score 8):

According to the `setStyle()` description in the [DialogFragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setStyle%28int,%20int%29):

> Calling this after the fragment's Dialog is created will have no
>   effect

Comment: thank you very much, it worked calling in constructor instead of createview or viewcreated

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, it is better to override theme getter

```
override fun getTheme(): Int {
    return R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme
}
```

Comment: Well done that man! I was only getting an unwanted actionbar title when using android 5.0. It wasn't a problem on Android 8 and 9 (didn't try other versions). This solution solved the problem of the unwanted title bar across all my tested versions.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to the onCreate method in DialogFragment:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_MinWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a custom theme for your a dialog you can do it this way...

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme) ...
```

Comment: Your answer is about AlertDialog while the question is about DialogFragment